# How can I align 2 first elements on the left and the last one on the right

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I think my code is in order, but I do not know why I am unable to organize my elements in this way:

```
|**   *|
```

This is my code:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    3
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? This is my live code: https://jsfiddle.net/uxpkh9nL/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `align-self: flex-end` (in *row flex-direction*, `align-self` and `align-items` align *flex items* in the *cross axis* which means vertically) - you can use `margin-left: auto` on the `right` element - see demo below:

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.container div{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.right{
  display:flex;
  /*align-self:flex-end;*/
  margin-left: auto; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>  
  <div class="right">
    3
  </div>  
</div>
```

---

I prefer using margins in this case but you can also use a *pseudo element* and use to *space out the items* and using `flex-grow: 1` on that.

- adding `order: 1` to the *flex items*, `order: 2` to the *pseudo element* and `order: 3` to the `right` elements *places* the flex items in that order.
- adding `flex-grow: 1` to the *pseudo element* forces it to fill all the remaining space left thereby *placing* the `right` element to the right end.

But this is an overkill if you ask me - see demo below:

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid red;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-start;
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
  flex-direction:row;
}
.container div{
  border:1px solid blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  order: 1; /* added */
}

.right{
  display:flex;
  /*align-self:flex-end;*/
  order: 3 !important; /* added */
}

.container:after { /* added */
  order: 2;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    1
  </div>
  <div>
    2
  </div>  
  <div class="right">
    3
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: it works, but ... is there any way to achieve it with flexbox?

Comment: you don't have any `justify-self` in *flexbox* - alignment in *flex axis* with margins *is* the flexbox way :) will add another option to the answer...

Comment: I'm just learning flexbox, it's something complex for me what you did, you can detail it please, since you're the best answer.